# MySQL get data from the table and check if userid is present in the table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, mysqli

I have a table called "**session**", the table has a column called "**userid**".

Example of the table:

```
ROW    userid
-------------
1      61
2      128
3      84
```

Now in my site I have articles listed all on ONE page, EACH article is written by a user, and EACH user has it's own **userid**

What I'm trying to achieve is: IF the user(userid=X) which wrote the article EXISTS in **session** table show a text..

Here is how I'm trying to get the userid from the session table ->

```
SELECT userid FROM #session
```

But I guess with this code it only takes ONE userid from the column not ALL of them...

Can someone give me a hand on this please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will select ALL userid's from session:

```
SELECT userid FROM session
```

...which is almost exactly the code you mentioned. However, you don't need to get a list of userid's, you just need to see if a certain id exists in the table. So, what you do is you count the number of instances that the userid is a specific value, which would look something like this (in php, using mysqli):

```
function is_id_in_session($db, $userid) {
    $total_result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM session WHERE userid = {$userid}");
    $total = $total_result->fetch_row();
    return ($total[0] > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have also database table for articles (table article with column userid) , you may use inner join in your query:

```
Select userid FROM article 
JOIN session using(userid)
```

This will get all users that are in session table and have the article